# Lollipop update issues

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

I have updated my Moto G2 to Lollipop 5.02,

1) After which facing Wifi issues, where it does not connect to saved networks, One has to remove the network from the saved networks and reconnect by entering the password.

2) The Photos folder shows up twice on the menu of apps

3) The Moto Assist, which reads out your message or answers the calls in Home or Driving mode does not work. the voice reads the message and then beeps to turn on the speaker to listen your reply to either send an sms or answer calls... keeps beeping until one has to exit out of the assist mode.

Guys, do let me know if anyone here are facing these issues after the update. How one can get rid of them :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Apps

uninstall all the updates to the apps (roll back apps to factory installed).

It worked on my phone (Moto G2).

resolved issues (checked and verified):
1. duplicate photo folder 
3. apps open instantly (else they took a long time to open and screen had to be locked and unlocked again for any app to open)